# Getting an error with custom validation in a Rails 3 ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activemodel

I'm trying to use the [Date Validator Gem](https://github.com/codegram/date_validator) but I am running into an error and I'm not sure if it's because the model isn't Active Record or not (I've seen people suggest that validation is a bit funky in ActiveModel when not in ActiveRecord).

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 & Rails 3.0.7. I've attached both the class and the error below.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Class**

```
require 'ice_cube'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/time_with_zone'
require 'ostruct'
require 'tzinfo'
require 'active_model'
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
extend ActiveModel::Naming
class Schedule
  attr_accessor :yaml, :repeat, :interval, :interval_unit, :start_time, :start_date, :end_date, :end_time, :ends, :on, :after, :monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday
  validates_presence_of :repeat, :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :end_time, :ends
  validates_presence_of :interval, :interval_unit, :if => :ends_never? 
  validates_presence_of :on, :if => :ends_on_date?
  validates_numericality_of :after, :greater_than => 0, :if => :ends_after_recurrences? 
  validates :start_date, :date => { :after => Time.now }
  validates :end_date, :date => { :after => :start_date }
  validates :on, :date => { :after => :end_date } 

  def initialize(attributes = {})
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  private
  def parse_schedule
    if :repeat == 0
      get_repeatable
    end

  end
  def parse_yaml
  end

  def ends_on_date?
    return :ends == "on"
  end
  def ends_never?
    return :ends == "never"
  end
  def ends_after_recurrences?
    return :ends == "after"
  end
end
```

**Error from Rails Console**

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > s = Schedule.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for DateValidator:Module
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:70:in `block in validates_with'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:69:in `each'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:69:in `validates_with'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in `block in validates'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:83:in `each'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:83:in `validates'
    from /Users/chance/Sites/EatingNow/app/models/schedule.rb:16:in `<class:Schedule>'
    from /Users/chance/Sites/EatingNow/app/models/schedule.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-expectations-2.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/backward_compatibility.rb:6:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included/extended the top-level namespace. Make sure the includes/extends are IN the class.

```
class Schedule

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
```

Comment: Ahha, thanks! Coming from java/c# I guess my brain completely ignored the example I was following and threw them above the class. I feel kinda like an idiot but really appreciate the help man, thanks!